# How to find out if a scrollbar is visible/attached in flutter?

Tags: flutter, web-applications, scrollbar

I want to add space/padding for a scrollbar when it is visible.

How can I find out, if a scrollbar is visible in a flutter widget?

Answer (score 0):

this lib can help you to do it
https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return VisibilityDetector(
    key: Key('my-widget-key'),
    onVisibilityChanged: (visibilityInfo) {
      var visiblePercentage = visibilityInfo.visibleFraction * 100;
      debugPrint(
          'Widget ${visibilityInfo.key} is ${visiblePercentage}% visible');
    },
    child: someOtherWidget,
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Amir The Scrollbar is automatically added by List, SingleChildScrollView, ... how does it work with the https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector - I didn't get it running in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Through the following I could find out if there is a scrollbar

```
NotificationListener<ScrollMetricsNotification>(
      onNotification: (notification) {
        setState(() {
          hasScrollbar = (notification.metrics.maxScrollExtent > 0);
        });
      },
```

and when hasScrollbar is true I add padding for it:

```
padding: hasScrollbar ? myThemeData.screenPadding.copyWith(right: 20.scaled()) : myThemeData.screenPadding,
```

Comment: What do you add this listener to though?